# What do 限定 and ポイント mean in this sentence about marketing?

Tags: translation, meaning, nouns

> 限定とポイントで買わないことを損にする

I am currently working on a difficult translation
to do with marketing that has very little context with a lot
of sentences in isolation.  It is to do with behavioural economics.
I'm wondering if anyone knows what 限定 and ポイント are referring to
in the above sentence. There is no context other than it is from a list of subtitles in a book to do with companies and their marketing strategies.

Also, does anyone know if ボリュームゾーン不況 could be translated as a 'recession in the volume zone'?

Comment: I think you should show us some research effort. ボリュームゾーン不況  reads "Volume Zone Recession".

Comment: Isn't ボリュームゾーン a wasei-eigo term? A safer term which I'm familiar with is "midrange" or "commodity".

Answer (score 3):

限定 is an abbreviation of 限定商品.

If you have a ポイントカード of a shop, you can get "points" according to your amount of purchase. The points can be accumulated and be used for later purchases. The word ポイント in your sentence means this reward system. This kind of ポイントシステム is very popular to enclose customers in Japan.

ボリュームゾーン不況 is explained in [this webpage](https://thepage.jp/detail/20150417-00000003-wordleaf).
This word seems a term coined in Japan, so you should find an appropriate English expression by yourself.